# Grab content from QuarkXPress file

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I’m trying to develop an E-Paper website using .Net. But At first the content of the website need to grab from the Quark file. What is the procedure to get the content from the Quark file according to the Layout?
 So it would be highly appreciated to provide some information regarding this subject.

Thanks…

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a tough project since the QuarkXpress files are 1) proprietary and therefore are not well documented, and 2) binary so the data is harder to get at. This will require a lot more work than a post on StackOverflow.com can help with.

First, ASP.NET really isn't the right framework for it. At least, you should develop this as a C# or VB code library project which is then consumed by a ASP.NET web application.

In order to parse the file, you might want to start off by reading [Reverse engineering the Quark Xpress file format](http://www.iwriteiam.nl/QX.html). This forum, [Code for QuarkXPress file format support](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=91141), also seems to have some good information. You will want to use what you learn from those articles to parse the binary and convert it to the proper types or structures. Here on some links on how to parse binary files in C#:

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/binaryreader
- [Read binary file into a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384/read-binary-file-into-a-struct-c)
- http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html

You may also want to check out this forum posting on [How to create dynamic QuarkXPress files in .Net FrameWork C#](http://forums.quark.com/t/18865.aspx). It seems that Quark has a C# API for dealing with Quark files if you have QuarkXpress Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff.
Indeed I wanted to build an e-Paper website like http://www.epaperarchives.com/SLIDEdemos/index.html#demolinks. I just need to grab the content from Quark file as Image by Layer to Layer. . I read some article which talked about QuarkXPress Server, Where I can Use web service within my application. If you think there are any other ways, I mean building without QuarkXPress file, so please response me.  
Thanks
RUSHO